# C# How to add checkbox to mvc webgrid?

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, checkbox, webgrid

I have a webgrid in a mvc project which I fill with values of a dynamic list. When I try to add a column of checkboxes it overwrites the entire grid and only shows checkboxes. I want them to be "added" to the webgrid. How can I do that?

```
    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "_Result";
    }

    @model MySite.Models.SearchModels.listModel

    @{
        var grid = new WebGrid(Model.liste);
    }

    <div style="background-color: #FAA719; padding: 50px; min-width:700px; margin-left:100px; margin-right:100px;">
        @grid.GetHtml(tableStyle: "webgrid-table",
            headerStyle: "webgrid-header",
            rowStyle: "webgrid-row-style",
            columns: grid.Columns(
            **grid.Column(header: "Select", format: @<text><input type="checkbox" /></text>))**
            )
    </div>
```

Comment: If your checkbox column is interfering with other columns as you claim then you'll have to show other columns in your code sample. Also, show us what the output is and what you expected to see.

Comment: I want a checkbox column next to the webgrid table. Basically I would like to understand how can one create a webgrid with checkbox column.

Comment: In your example you don't have any other columns, only the checkbox, so that's all you'll see. Add some more columns that contain the other fields from your model, but keep the checkbox column in the position you want it. 
You'll also want to add some data-attributes to the checkbox inputs so that you can identify the record later, and an event handler at the grid/table level to handle clicks to your checkboxes.

Comment: Other columns are coming from model.

var grid = new WebGrid(Model.liste);

I just want to add another column of checkboxes next to them.
If I add all the columns as in the code I cannot use sorting feature of webgrid.

I have a dynamic list filled with the grid entries I must display them how do you suggest to display them is webgrid the right choice?

Comment: As soon as you specify the `columns` parameter to `@grid.GetHtml()`, then the webgrid will no longer auto-generate columns for model properties, and you will have to recreate them all as parameters to `columns` - that's why you're only getting a single column of checkboxes.

Comment: I solved it.

If you specify the column name same as in the dynamic list it automatically fills the table with that columns values.

Now I will work on how to get which checkbox is selected.